# Facebook URL - Angularjs how to get current url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, url, facebook-page

If you are using a page tab on facebook, you can connect other websites inside the iframe. I want to get the url of facebook within the facebook page. when I am trying to get window.location.url, it shows my website url, how to do it in facebook page to get facebook url

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Your Facebook application exists within an iframe, which cannot access the parent window on facebook.com due to same-origin restrictions in all major browsers. It is effectively sandboxed.

However, the Facebook [signed request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request) will include the ID of the Facebook Page your tab is being accessed on.

Comment: @AbelAnojanSithamparappillai My answer doesn't change based on your wishes.

Comment: Note that this info will only be contained inside the POST parameter of that name (there's other places where you can get a version of a signed_request, like f.e. the JS SDK) - so you need a server-side component to be able to access it, it can not be accessed client-side only.

Comment: I solved it guys.  window.location != window.parent.location;